# zfs-2.1.12 with kernel 6.3.8-200.fc38.x86_64

Tags: kernel-modules, zfs

zfs latest version is supposed to run on 6.3, but on fedora 38 (after installed zfs-2.1.12-1.fc38.x86_64) I get this after issued modprobe zfs:

`modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/6.3.8-200.fc38.x86_64`

any clue? Or should I downgrade the kernel to 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

recompiling zfs source code fixed the issue